# how to design navigation drawer with child list view?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

I need to design navigation drawer with additional 3 times child list view, I implemented now single child list view.
Now how can i implement with 3 times nested list view in navighation drawer.
Please find attachment for clarification of my idea.
[image]

Comment: you can use one provided by android studio template and edit menu.xml according to your need

Comment: dear do u see my image?? i need to implement exapandable. i need your idea.

Comment: yes but have you seen what I am saying

Comment: yes, that is not possible , now i have already done this project.. I need to create it in java code.

Comment: @Aditya yes you are right..thanks

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just have a look at this [library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). It has got what you are looking for and so much more.

Setting up a Navigation Drawer using this library is a few minutes task and it is well built and maintained.